# ASP Development Server Access running on Parallels VM

Tags: asp.net, web-services, windows-7, virtual-machine

I've seen some discussion on the topic of running an ASP Dev Server in a VM where access is required from MacOS but have had no success so far in getting access. I wondered if anyone out there can point out where I might be going wrong.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm using Parallels 6 running a Windows 7  VM on MacOS Snow Leopard.

I'm running a simple Webservice developed in Visual Web Developer Express 2008 at the following address on my VM:

http://localhost:25000/Service1.svc/

I've built a test client that communicates with the service from within the VM environment ok so I'm pretty sure that the code side of things is ok.

My problem is now that I want to test the service from the MacOS side. I've built a simple client in XCode to communicate with the service but simply cannot connect to the server.

I've installed a WAMP server in the Windows7 VM and was able to get access from the MacOS side - just to check that it's not a general connectivity problem, but thats fine.

I guess my question comes down to, when you run/develop a WebService and you want to run in Debug mode - the webservice runs at http://localhost: in the context of an ASP Development environment. Should the webservice be visible from outside the VM? If so what steps do I need to take to ensure that it is visible?

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you are using the cassini web server that is built into studio (webdev.webserver)?  This mini-web server does not allow remote connections to connect, it only alows connections from a local machine.  There are some hacks ([Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683151/connect-remotely-to-webdev-webserver-exe), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220274/remote-machines-cannot-connect-to-visual-studio-web-server)) to allow this, but for your needs, your best bet is to use [IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/) or full blown IIS.